# Memory usage inside the VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox, memory

I created a VirtualBox VM with Oracle Solaris.

I have a host with 8G and give 4G to the VM.

Now after reboot I installed Solaris Studio there and compiled my project.

After that I exited Studio and inside the Terminal I issued "top"

To my surprise I see:

```
158 processes, 148 sleeping, 1 on CPU
CPU state: 92.5% idle, 3.2% user, 4.2% kernel
Kernel: 389 ctxsw, .......
Memory: 4096M phys mem, 1884M free mem, 4096M total swap, 3332M free swap
```

So the free memory is about half of the existing memory allocated to the VM.

Is it normal?

All I'm running is the Terminal - nothing else, besides GNOME3.

I'm asking because:

1. I can't run my program - it crashes inside GTK because of insufficient memory.
2. I can't install Oracle - it says "size of availablle memory is less than the memory needed to create database.", when running step3 of the installer.

TIA!

Comment: It's absolute not clear what you did and where. Are you talking about a VM? A host PC? What did you reboot and why. It's all mixed up.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov, I'm talking about a VM. After Solaris install I did reboot the VM, log back in and install Solaris Studio. Then grabbed my project from git, started the IDE and compiled it. Then closed the IDE and issues the `top`. At the time of the `top` only the Terminal was running. 1 instance. Nothing else.